# Having an issue with mutablemap in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mutablemap

I'm working on an algorithm type challenge, and i am debugging via print statements and i can't seem to figure out why the the values for keys are not what i am expecting

```
 var mapNums = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()

//imaginary array
    //var nums = [34,28,11,21,3,34,8,7,34,7,31,7,3,28,18]
    var count = 0
    

    for (n in nums) {

        if (mapNums.containsKey(n)) {
            count ++
            mapNums[n] = count
        } else if (!mapNums.containsKey(n)) {
            count = 1
            mapNums[n] = count
        }

    }

    println(mapNums)

//prints {34=2, 28=4, 11=1, 21=1, 3=3, 8=1, 7=2, 31=1, 18=1}
```

as you can see the key and values aren't what theyre supposed to be and i am not sure why.

Comment: What is your algorithm supposed to do?

Comment: change `else if` to `else` and override `count` not increase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to generate the desired map:

```kotlin
val nums = intArrayOf(34, 28, 11, 21, 3, 34, 8, 7, 34, 7, 31, 7, 3, 28, 18).toList()
println(nums.groupingBy { it }.eachCount())
```

[try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/oWB2Zyop9)

Here `groupingBy` creates a `Grouping` source using the same element as the key selector. Then `eachCount` groups elements from the Grouping source by key and counts elements in each group.

You can also refer the documentation for more info about [groupingBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) and [eachCount](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/each-count.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's because you reuse the same `count` variable outside of the loop so it keeps incrementing from different keys.

Instead you should get the current count from the map, then put it back one higher:

```
val nums = intArrayOf(34,28,11,21,3,34,8,7,34,7,31,7,3,28,18)
val mapNums = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()

for (n in nums) {
    val count = mapNums[n] ?: 0
    mapNums[n] = count + 1
}

println(mapNums) // {34=3, 28=2, 11=1, 21=1, 3=2, 8=1, 7=3, 31=1, 18=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check n number is contain this map as key, if found then increment 1 its value using plus method. If not found any value from the map, it will null and check if null and set 1.

```
       var mapNums = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
       //imaginary array
        var nums = arrayOf(34,28,11,21,3,34,8,7,34,7,31,7,3,28,18)
        
        for (n in nums) {
    
        mapNums[n] = mapNums[n]?.plus(1) ?: 1
    
        }
    
        println(mapNums)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation